# checking for empty ajax response

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I want to check if the ajax response is null or not. If its null then in this case it should `alert "somthing";` but its not alerting so. What might be problem with this code. Please help me.

```
 $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "<?php echo base_url().'index.php/cms/notification'; ?>",

            data: {

            },

            beforeSend: function()
            {

            },
            success: function(data)
            {
              if(data != null)
              {
                  alert("somthing");
               }
             }
            });
```

Correct code:

```
   $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "<?php echo base_url().'index.php/cms/notification'; ?>",

            data: {

            },

            beforeSend: function()
            {

            },
            success: function(data)
            {
              if(data != "")
              {
                  alert("somthing");
               }
             }
            });
```

Comment: Where exactly do you have that code? Can you confirm that request returns empty json parenthensis? i.e. in Chrome Developer Tools.

Comment: Look at your browser's developer tools. Look at the JavaScript console. Does it report any errors? Look at the Net tab. Is the request being made? Does it get a response? Do they contain the data you expect?

Comment: `if(data)`, server will be returning nothing, not `null` or `undefined`

Comment: @Saqueib — The server *could* be returning a JSON text consisting of `null`. If it returns nothing than it wouldn't be JSON and the success function wouldn't fire.

Comment: @FrantišekMaša — JSON doesn't use parenthesis.

Comment: i saw at console. and the ajax is running successfully and it returns and empty response. Actully my data is not in json format.

Comment: you heard the man @Quentin

Comment: @Quentin Of course I meant curly brackets. Thx

Comment: @FrantišekMaša — `{} != null` either though.

Comment: @Quentin You misunderstand. I just pointed out that "empty json" can also be {} , which of course doesn't match the pattern.

Answer (score 1):

> Actully my data is not in json format.

You've told jQuery that your data is JSON but you aren't returning JSON.

The `success` function won't fire because jQuery won't parse it successfully.

Either use the `error` function instead or fix your server side code so it returns JSON.

Comment: i edited my question.. n tried after removing `datatype:json` though its not working.

Comment: Now the jQuery will parse it as whatever the content-type says it is. JSON is the only supported data format capable of representing `null`. So whatever value you have, it won't be `null`.

Comment: oh thank you.  I removed `datatype: json;` and instead did `if(data !="")` and it worked what i aspect. Thank you for sugesstion.

Answer (score 0):

use code:

```
 if(data == undefined){
    alert("undefined data");
 }
```

Comment: JSON doesn't have an `undefined` data type, and if the response isn't JSON then the success function wouldn't fire.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(data != null) {
    alert("something");
}
```

Actually it's the opposite. Empty response **won't** process that code.